# pgfgantt: Can't get the examples work correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I need to make some Gantt Diagrams for a budget, and found on the web the pgfgantt package, which looks amazing.

Unfortunately I can't make it work correctly with the examples of its documentation.

I'm trying [this example](http://pastie.org/3516017), compiling it with [this version](http://pastie.org/3516050) pdflatex and getting [this log](http://pastie.org/3516027). This is a screenshoot of the generated PDF:
[image: obtained pdf]

And one of the expected result from the docs:
[image: expected pdf]

I'm pretty new to latex, and sincerely have no idea what is going wrong. Any help would be MUCH apreciated :D

EDIT: [Here is a log](http://pastie.org/private/aw2xvrfljtzbva3ye00v9a) of compiling the example with `\listfiles` at the beginning of the doc as suggested by Alan Munn.

Comment: This compiles fine for me (TeXLive 2011). It's likely that you have an old version of `pgf` installed. Try putting `\pgfversion` right after `\begin{document}`. It should output 2.10.  If it does, put `\listfiles` as the first line of your document, compile it again and post a link to the log.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! \pgfversion gives me "2.10", I added the output with \listfiles to the question

Comment: Your version of `pgfgantt` is out of date.  Mine is `2012/01/25 v3.0` yours is `2011/11/10 v2.1`

Comment: I haven't payed much attention to that as this example was also available in older docs, but after installing all the other texlive archlinux's packages, and updating pgfgantt.sty by hand, it's now working! Thanks for your time :D

Comment: I'm glad it worked. We can close this question as too localized, then. (You don't need to do anything.)